# What's the best way to append a StrBuf to a StrBuf?

Tags: fantom

I have a series of StrBuf objects and want to know the most efficient way to concatenate them together.

There's the `add()` method but the docs say, "[Add x.toStr to the end of this buffer](http://fantom.org/doc/sys/StrBuf.html#add)". If I'm doing this over and over and over again, I'd imagine that `StrBuf.toStr()` is not that performant.

(I know the real answer is to just use the one StrBuf, but humour me here!)

Cheers.

**UPDATE:**

Looking at the Java source, under the hood `StrBuf` uses a Java `StringBuilder` which uses a char array as it's internal buffer. So `@Adrian`, yeah, it's important to have a large initial buffer.

As far as `StrBuf.toStr()` is concerned, a new Java String is created using `Arrays.copyOfRange()` - which is reasonable but unnecessary given there's an `append(StringBuffer sb)` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really - there are no optimizations in StrBuf for that case.  You seeing performance issues with what you have today?

Generally for our APIs we would pass around the `OutStream` instance from `StrBuf.out` and not the actual `StrBuf` instance.  Not sure if that helps your case or not.

Comment: Thanks, "there are no optimizations in StrBuf for that case" is the answer I was looking for. :(

Yeah, looking at the src I can see `add(Obj x)` essentially calls `x.toStr` - as this method is core, I guess I was wondering if it tried to do anything clever.

Comment: No performance issues, I'm just attempting some premature optimisation!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you could create a new StrBuf with a big enough capacity:

```
capacity
    Int capacity
    The number of characters this buffer can hold without allocating more memory.

make
    new make(Int capacity := 16)
    Create with initial capacity (defaults to 16)
```

Comment: Cheers, though I am currently creating a large initial StrBuf - I was more concerned with the overhead of the `toStr()` method before I add it.